# How to include multiple C files for compilation in kernel code? (OpenCL framework)

Tags: c, parallel-processing, compilation, gpu, opencl

I have a C file named bigd_testing.cpp which later will be the Kernel Code for my OpenCL Program. For bigd_testing.cpp to compile, i need to include bigd.c and bigdigits.c.

`gcc bigd.c bigdigits.c bigd_testing.cpp -O3` (Ubuntu)

(Never mind the .cpp extension. The code is written in C99).

I have a hunch that when i convert bigd_testing.cpp to Kernel code, since the Kernel code is compiled at runtime, it will throw an error because bigd.c and bigdigits.c are not linked.
(For example, only `gcc bigd_testing.cpp -O3` (or whatever compiler OpenCL is using) will be executed at runtime).

I tried adding #include "bigd.c" and #include "bigdigits.c" inside bigd_testing.cpp, but it is not working. I also tried just copy and pasting both bigd.c & bigdigits.c at the start of bigd_testing.cpp, but that also didnt work.
I wanted to sort this problem out first before starting the tedious process of converting the whole file as a string for the Kernel code.

Edit 1 - Seeing other posts now makes me wonder if the Kernel Code will throw any errors for my code because i do have .h header files like stdio.h, bigd.h included using #include. Will that cause any errors?

**Background Explained** - I have to do certain mathematical calculations over a spectrum (range - 1 trillion). These calculations are independent of each other over the spectrum. Running with a 8 core CPU and using all cores simultaneously is taking over 7 months. That is where i need OpenCL to utilize the GPU cores which i imagine are in hundreds. Parallel processing can work since the calculations are independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

In your OpenCL C source file `bigd_testing.cpp` (typically, these use the `.cl` file extension), you can at the top of the file place `#include "bigd.c"` and `#include "bigdigits.c"`, this works. The OpenCL compiler has a preprocessor, which can do `#include` (copy-paste the file contents), or other things like `#ifdef...#else...#endif` or `#define ...` macros.

The error in your case is caused by your headers themselves including `stdio.h` and other standard C headers that are incompatible with OpenCL's limitations on C99. You cannot include most headers that are not specifically written in OpenCL C. As a workaround, try to implement the functionality that you need yourself in OpenCL C.